# Not able to check the correctness of the SDE connection file

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase

I have passed willingly wrong parameters while creating the SDE connection through "CreateDatabaseconnnection_management". How can I check if it is a correct workspace that is linked with my GDB, before using the workspace. I have googled it, but got the describe would work.

Comment: desc=arcpy.describe("some improper connection file")

Comment: If the description object is a Workspace, then the connection was successful.  Lots of ways to get there, though, which is why code is required.

Comment: Whenever i tries to check it's type it does wroksout.Means nothing is returned, not even "None"

Comment: Please edit the question to contain what you have tried so far.  Usually try...except blocks are frowned upon, but you really ought to be using one here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I dont understand the question, requirements fully - but if you have a "bad" connection file and you want to make sure its "bad", you can simply try listing the featureclasses or do some action against the connection file. You should get back **no** results.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/path/to/connection.sde"
FCs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
if FCs is None or FCs == "" or len(FCs) == 0:
  print("assumed connection file is invalid")
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest.But in case the workspace is intended to be empty all through the code. Then how can i check whether the connection is "bad" or "good"?